# What can uniquely identify a phone? Phone number? IMEI? DeviceID?

Tags: android

I'm making an application which demands each user be unique. I want to prompt the user at first launch for a username and then tie that to that phone in Firebase. I understand getting phone number is tricky and not the most wide of choices, is there any other unique identifier for a phone?

Comment: [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMEI is unique for every device so each phone has a different IMEI number. Phone number is not as reliable as they may change or be swapped.

Comment: Just thought id mention... like IMEI, The SIMs IMSI (International Mobile Subscriber Identity) can be used to tie the user to a SIM card, depends on what the OP is trying to achieve.